# UITab Under View

Tags: ios, view, autolayout

How would I put a UI Tab under a UIView using autolayout programatically ?

I am trying to do it myself but it seems to be giving me errors about unsatisfiable constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James,

I don't think there is a class in the Cocoa API that is named "UI Tab" I did however manage to stumble across the below link, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html

That being said, as the document explains, "creating a tab bar programmatically"

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

   tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];



   MyViewController* vc1 = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

   MyOtherViewController* vc2 = [[MyOtherViewController alloc] init];



   NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];

   tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;



    window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

}
```

You then add tab bar items, to the newly created view controller as the document states.

Comment: Sorry I mean't UITabBar, I want it to appear below a UITableView. The Tab Bar should be anchored to the bottom of the screen with the UITableView Filling the Screen. I'm not sure if Autlayout is good for this

Comment: @JamesCampbell take a look at this project, https://github.com/cbpowell/CPPickerView

someone in NSChat recommended it to me.